# MySQL - Multiple Rows or JSON

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I'm building an app in Laravel and have a design question regarding my MySQL db.
Currently I have a table which defines the skills for all the default characters in my game.  Because the traits are pulled from a pool of skills, and have a variable number, one of my tables looks something like this:

```
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
| ID | CharID | SkillID | SkillScore|
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
|  1 |      1 |      15 |       200 |
|  2 |      1 |      16 |       205 |
|  3 |      1 |      12 |       193 |
|  4 |      2 |      15 |       180 |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Note the variable number of rows for any given `CharID`. With my Base Characters entered, I'm at just over 300 rows.

My issue is storing User's copies of their (customized)characters. I don't think storing 300+ rows per user makes sense. Should I store this data in a JSON Blob in another table? Should I be looking at a NoSQL solution like Mongo? Appreciate the guidance.

NB: The entire app centers around using the character's different skills. Mostly reporting from them, but users will also be able to update their SkillScore (likely a few times a week).

ps. Should I consider breaking each character out into their own table and tracking user's characters that way? Users won't be able to add/remove the skills from characters, only update them.

TIA.

Comment: As long as you have indexed the tables properly, I don't see any harm in having 300 rows per user. MySQL can easily handle millions of rows in a table..

Comment: IIRC, Facebook used MySQL in production up to 2014. The fact that MySQL is "slow" according to some people doesn't mean it can't do what it was designed for: storing lots of relational data in an accessible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pivot table looks good to me.

I'd consider dropping the ID column (unless you need it), and using a composite primary key:

```
PRIMARY_KEY(CharID, SkillID)
```

Primary keys are indexed so you will get efficient lookups.

As for your other suggestions, if you store this in a JSON column, you'll lose the ability to perform joins, and will therefore end up executing more queries.